# playframework - how to set a select input in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

So I have a form on a page, and I am trying to pre load all the old value when the page loads up. But I am having some trouble achieving this for the select object.

I have the following scala code for generating the select:

```
<select id="networkInterfaces">
            <option value="">First Available</option>
            @for(interface <- networkInterfaces) {
                @if(interface.Name == configs.last.networkInterfaceName) {
                    <option selected="selected" value="@interface.Name">@interface.DisplayName</option>
                } else {
                    <option value="@interface.Name">@interface.DisplayName</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

And when the page loads it does show that the selected network interface is selected. But the problem is if I change some of my other settings and submit it is returning the options html not the value. Is there a way to select the form value for the select in scala while the page is loading?
Is there something fundamental I am missing? Otherwise I will change the way it is handled to process display name rather than value...

**EDIT**

As I could not get this to work i changed the value to @interface.DisplayName and then converted it in code on the server. I would like to be able to do it properly but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: In the condition `interface.Name == configs.last.networkInterfaceName` you compare same datatypes? If it's `String` - maybe try `firstString.contentEquals(secondString)`?

Answer (score 6):

Is that correct that `<select id="networkInterfaces">` has no `name` specified?

and than you should use play helper `@select` and `Form` object. I think its the better way to handle form values.

```
@(form : Form[ABean])
@import helper._

@select(
form("configs.last.networkInterfaceName"),
options(networkInterfaces),
'_label -> "Interface Name",
'_default -> "First Available"
)
```

Further info about  helper `@select` visit :
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html

Comment: Thx jmuok, Currently my select is displaying the correct information, but when it loads the value is being set to the label not the value. Also does your select statement statement select an option on load?

Comment: yes，it will be selected the form value currently is by default.

Comment: form("configs.last.networkInterfaceName") trying to place here the string for the field name failed, this should be a callable but what callable?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
    <input type="hidden" id="groupIdRef" name="groupIdRef" value="@userRecord.groupId">
    @input(field=userRecordform("groupId"),'_label -> "") { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
        <select id="groupId" name="groupId" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)>
            options.map { v =>
                @for(g <- groups){
                  <option value=@g.id >@g.displayName</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    } 


// User JavaScript this onload function
window.onload = function() {    
document.getElementById('groupId').value = document.getElementById('groupIdRef').value;
}
```

It is work for me.